# Can I implement the Visual Studio's Live Visual Tree programmatically?

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

It seems that I can [debug any arbitrary UWP app with the Live Visual Tree in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999718/how-to-inspect-the-visual-tree-of-any-uwp-app). I also know you can do similar things with [XAML Spy](http://xamlspy.com/) and [XAML Inspector](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=xamlinspector).

How do these tools work? Is there a public UWP/Windows Runtime/Win32 API that I can call to get the XAML tree, just like I can get [diagnostic info](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/) or the [UIA tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-howto-walk-uiautomation-tree)?

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Comment: Why you want to implement this feature?

Comment: For the same reason that I would use the diagnostic APIs to make a task manager replacement or write my own debugger---to learn more about the system I'm using, and to understand how different parts of Windows work. Besides, I don't particularly enjoy using Visual Studio, and I would love to be able to do XAML debugging from the command line.